# Reading from a text file into a 2D array representing a month

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I need to read a list of temperatures from a text file.

This is what the text will look like.
The '6' on the first line indicates the number of weeks listed for the month. The columns are the days of the week, starting with Sunday, and '-10' is a placeholder to indicate that there was no day in that position for the month. In the example file the month begins on a Friday and ends on a Sunday.

```
6
-10    -10    -10    -10    -10    8.7    7.8
9.2    13.7   16.1   18.1   18.6   14.7   15.7
14.5   16.4   17.9   20.5   14.9   16.4   20.3
21.2   15.1   10.4   11.8   17     17.3   13.8
9.9    7.8    6.4    9.4    9.4    13     16
17.9   -10    -10    -10    -10    -10    -10
```

My function needs to read the temperatures from the file and then return them as a 2D array.

```
double ** readtemp(string filename, int &weeks)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    if (!infile)
        exit(1);
    infile >> weeks;
    double ** address = new double *[weeks], read_test;

    for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        address[i] = new double[7];
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {

            if (infile >> read_test)
                address[i][j] = read_test;
            else
                address[i][j] = -10;
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return address;
}
```

I am having a problem when reading a month that does not begin on Sunday.  When the month does not start on a Sunday the array "pulls" all the other days out of line. I can't get it to insert '-10' on those missing days at the start of the month.

Comment: The syntax he used actually does make `read_test` a `double`, not a `double **`.  Why the language works that way I have no idea.

Comment: @SamMarinelli - You are correct in regards to it being a double. As I said in my original comment, my C++ is a bit rusty. Also, for readability sake, I never declare variables like that :)

Comment: Ditto.  I only do `double x, * y, ** z;`.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any "missing days" because you've already put `-10` in the text file for days for which you don't have data.  Just read them in with no special regard to the number `-10`.

```
double ** readtemp(string filename, int &weeks)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    if (!infile)
        exit(1);
    infile >> weeks;
    double ** address = new double *[weeks], read_test;

    for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        address[i] = new double[7];
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {

            if (infile >> read_test)
                address[i][j] = read_test;
            else
                throw runtime_error("Read failed.");
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return address;
}
```

Comment: that's the point, all the -10 won't be in the text that will be read. I uploaded the output + the number of weeks.
I just put them there so you could see...

And I cannot add any other function

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, but the basic problem in comprehending the exact root of the problem is  **When the month does not start on a Sunday the array "pulls" all the other days out of line** . Given that the statement is ambiguous, and also given that you could test what these lines by adding a helper function like:

```
void print(double **data , int weeks , int cols)
{
string days[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
for (int x = 0; x < weeks; x++)
{ 
    cout << "On the #" << (x + 1) << " Week\r\n";
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
    {
        cout << "---Temp On " << days[y] + " was: " << data[x][y] << "---\r\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Really cannot tell where you are wrong here??